# Kinect 0 does not exist

Tags: usb, usb-device

I'm trying to set up the **AR Sandbox** and I'm having a tough go of it. I can't seem to get **KinectUtil** to pull the intrinsic calibration data from the kinect unit. When I use the *KinectUtil list* command, it will (sometimes) give me the serial and location of the kinect.

When it comes time to run *KinectUtil getCalib 0*, it will come up with an error saying the kinect does not exist.

I am trying to troubleshoot this issue. There are a couple of problems that have been suggested to me; it could be a bad kinect unit, a faulty power source, or a messed up USB controller. I have no idea how to check for these issues, short of buying new parts and trying them out.

I am running Linux mint 19 and using a kinect 1473.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Vrui, making sure to set up libusb1, and this helped the stability a bit. I can now usually get access to the Kinect.There are issues with connectivity remaining, but it seems to be an issue with the computer's internal USB hub.

UPDATE: Tried a fresh install on a new computer, the problem was the same. The issue was likely in the Kinect itself. Bought a new Kinect and things are working better.